# Identifying connections and active SQL in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, android-activity, monitor, connection

How do I see the currently executing SQL statements in SQL Server? I've poked around in SQL Server Management Studio, but I don't see anything "canned".

Answer (score 2):

Profiler will log, and allow you to view, all activity on the server, if that's what you're looking for.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx

Comment: just make sure you have permission to run profiler in sql server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187611.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The active connections can be listed with the built in stored procedures `sp_who` and `sp_who2`. At least one of them (don't remember which one right now) shows executing commands on the exact time when the sp is run.

As mentioned in another answer, sql server profiler is a great tool which gives much more detail and logging of activity. The sp:s just provides a quick overview.

Answer (score 1):

Activity Monitor (in SSMS under Management) is a GUI version of sp_who2.  To identify the T-SQL being executed, run DBCC Inputbuffer and the SPID, eg,

```
DBCC inputbuffer(54)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server DMV's are great for finding information like this.  For example the sys.dm_exec_connections table will show you a lot about the user connected to your database.

If it is of interest, our Cotega service has the ability to do an [analysis of your database](http://cotega.com/docs/analyze_database) and show you this as well as a lot of other things (such as top queries by CPU, IO, etc) which is available to even the free accounts.

I hope that helps.